# Eloquent Exception: A four digit year could not be found Data missing when using protected dates

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent

I'm refactoring an old application using Eloquent as DBAL/Active Record all is going fine but when i add "protected $dates" to my model i got this nasty error:

```
Warning: array_map(): An error occurred while invoking the map callback in [CUT]\vendor\illuminate\support\Collection.php on line 1024

Exception: A four digit year could not be found Data missing
```

This is my model:

```
class dbPazienti extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'pazienti';
    protected $primaryKey = 'pkid';
    protected $dates = ['DataNascita','Richiamareil','deleted_at'];
    protected $fillable = ['Titolo','Nome','SecondoNome','Cognome','CodiceFiscale','Indirizzo','Cap','Localita','Provincia','Telefono','Email','Sesso','DataNascita','ComuneNascita','ProvinciaNascita','MedicoCurante','Note','Richiamareil'];

    public function ecografie()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('dbEcografie', 'fk_idPaziente', 'pkid');
    }

    public function scopeMedicoDiBase($query, $mdb=0)
    {
        return $query->with(['ecografie' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('mdb', '=', $mdb);
        }]);
    }

}
```

If i comment this line i don't get any error:

```
protected $dates = ['DataNascita','Richiamareil','deleted_at'];
```

but of course then this fields are not treated as dates

These are the values for those fields in the database:

- 1962-09-20 00:00:00
- 0000-00-00 00:00:00
- NULL
- 2015-12-28

How can i fix this? Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am unfamiliar with this language but the first thing I would look at is if the language can treat Null as a date and if it can treat 0000-00-00 00:00:00.

If you are unsure you could spend some time googling or what might be a fast intuitive way of figuring it out is trying to do it with the Null but with the 0000-00-00 00:00:00 and visa versa and then try without either.

If you get the error when only one of those two is present it is your problem. If you get the error when either is present then they are both problems. If you get the error with neither present then there is something else going on but hey you tired and maybe learned something in the process.

Comment: I already tried that, infact one of the fields contains only date in these formats 1962-09-20 00:00:00 or 2015-12-28 and the error still present itself (i commented the other 2 while testing)

Comment: Dang worth a shot sorry.